# SQL SERVER DB Closed PHP Connection

Tags: sql-server, laravel, sql-server-2008, odbc, sql-server-2016

I am using php laravel to connect to a sql server db, but there is an issue sql server db "closed php connection". When I check requests in Profiler Trace, I have 2 requests: first one is from php audit login, then audit logout. The query doesn't complete, and I don't know why.

1) This error I get it from laravel:

> SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   (SQL: select * from contact)

2) Image from [SQL SERVER Profiler Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfxWZ.png)

Comment: Is this SQL Server 2008 or 2016? The answer may vary depending on the version.

Comment: same issue with both